# how to do you use letter-spacing smaller than 1px

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, letter-spacing

I have a web font that I am trying to get the spacing just right. I have it set at letter-spacing: .03px. Works great in firefox 5, But i know this doesn't work across browsers. Is there anything i can do to help this? or what browsers would this work in?

```
font-family: 'FSS Light',Times;
font-size: 15px;
letter-spacing: 0.3px;
line-height: 20px;
margin: 0 0 1em;
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that sub-pixel spacing *can* work, in a medium in which the pixel is the smallest unit of measure...I'd be interested in being proven wrong, though.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried with em

```
letter-spacing: .5em;
```

Yes Ems works on all browsers and they are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.

Comment: Yes, you can use small `em` values on all browsers.

Comment: @Andrew Peacock even a .04em?

Comment: I got it to go to the hundredths place (i.e `.04em`), but it won't go any smaller than `.01em`.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Warface, you could em, cm or whatever. 
But if you need your letters to get closer together, you can also use negative values.

```
letter-spacing: -1px;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eZbYB/2/